# File content redirection to args doesn't works

Tags: java, redirect, console, pipeline, args

I was testing a little piece of code that I need to implement in a Java school project.

```
public class Prova {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       System.out.println(args.length);

       for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
           System.out.print(args[i]);
       }

       System.out.print("\nEnd!");
    }
}
```

When I type in the console `java Prova < test.dot` while the content of the `test.dot` file is:

```
digraph G1 {
c -> e;
a -> e;
a -> f;
f -> b;
g;
}
```

I just get this:

```
C:\Users\Lorenzo\workspace\Progetto_ASD\bin>java Prova < test.dot
0

End!
```

I tryed `java Prova > output.txt` just to see if the pipe worked and it does (I get the same as above but in a file).

If I try `type test.dot` I get:

```
C:\Users\Lorenzo\workspace\Progetto_ASD\bin>type test.dot
digraph G1 {
c -> e;
a -> e;
a -> f;
f -> b;
g;
}
```

As I would expect.

I really don't know what's wrong with what I'm doing (I'm using Windows by the way).

Comment: When you redirect the file content to input, you simulate an user input, not some arguments passed via comma line.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't know that. Solved.

Comment: I added some details for both approaches.

Comment: Assuming you are using Unix like system then `java Prova < test.dot` can be read using System.in and line by line using a `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 2 different approaches:

1. `args`

   You should run the program as `java Prova arg1 arg2 ... argn`:

   > `java Prova "digraph G1 {" "c -> e;" "a -> e;" "a -> f;" "f -> b;" g; }`

   and probably you want to change

   ```
   System.out.print(args[i]);
   ```

   to

   ```
   System.out.println(args[i]);
   ```

   to have 7 different lines.
2. **Redirection**

   This is equivalent to a program that accepts your **input from keyboard**. You can change your program to look like this:

   ```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;

   public class Prova {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           String line;
           try {
               while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                   System.out.println(line);
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   and then call

   > `java Prova < test.dot`.

Answer (score -1):

are you reading from a file ? 
So you need to know more about the java.io.FileInputStream

this is an example of code can help you
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-in-java-fileinputstream

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFileExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C:/robots.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                    + fis.available());

            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                // convert to char and display it
                System.out.print((char) content);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ps: you need to close the stream and release any ressource for a good practice.